# Store login state in sqlite or share Preference

Tags: java, android, sqlite, sharedpreferences

I making the app, in my app i making the login screen hy registration screen, i want to store the login state  if the user login the app then he never login again until the user logout the app, but i nor know where the Shared Preference code are implements, Kindly give me a suitable solution
Thats my full login screen code screenshots

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: you can use shared preference , when logout clear all value of preference except login key.

Answer (score 0):

You can use shared preference. It is so easy to use.

```
SharedPreferences userDetails =getSharedPreferences("userdetails", MODE_PRIVATE);
                    Editor edit = userDetails.edit();
                    edit.clear();
                    edit.putString("username", "");
                    edit.putString("password", "");
                    edit.commit();
```

Also you can get the data with;

```
userDetails.getString("username", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public class Pref {

        private  static final String PREF_FILE = BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID.replace(".","_");
        private static SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = null;

        private static void openPref(Context context) {
            sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        }

        //For string value
        public static String getValue(Context context, String key,String defaultValue) {
            Pref.openPref(context);
            String result = Pref.sharedPreferences.getString(key, defaultValue);
            Pref.sharedPreferences = null;
            return result;
        }

        public static void setValue(Context context, String key, String value) {
            Pref.openPref(context);
            Editor prefsPrivateEditor = Pref.sharedPreferences.edit();
            prefsPrivateEditor.putString(key, value);
            prefsPrivateEditor.commit();
            Pref.sharedPreferences = null;
        }

        //You can create method like above for boolean, float, int etc...
    }
```

If you want to store string data than you can write like below:

```
Pref.setValue(mContext,"test", "Test123");
```

If you want to fetch string data than you can write like below

```
Pref.getValue(mContext,"test", "your default value");
```

this one return String value as "Test123". If you getvalue without setvalue than it will return your default value here it is "your default value".

when you have to logout clear preferences like below

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
editor.clear(); 
editor.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

### you have store Preferences like this simple example

```
//use this code to login successfully so store login status true in Preferences
    getSharedPreferences("user",MODE_PRIVATE)
       .edit().putBoolean("isLogin",true).commit();

//-----then open app again to check user already login or not-------------------------

boolean isLogin = getSharedPreferences("user",MODE_PRIVATE)
                .getBoolean("isLogin",false);

        if(isLogin)
        {
            //this user is login
        }else {
            //go to login screen this user is not login
        }
```